# How to add a column to a two dimension array using google app script/javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a 2 dimensional array as shown below. Now I want to add 3 more columns (Col E, Col F , Col G) and these three columns should have parsed values from Col D.

Either modifying existing array k (OR) create a new array.

**Input:**

```
k=[
 [Col A, Col B, Col C, Col D], 
 [1, A, 8, [(P0, 1), (P2, 7), (P1, 1)]],
 [2, B, 4, [(P2, 4)]], 
 [3, C, 13,[(P2, 1)]]]
```

**Output:**

```
[Col A, Col B, Col C, Col D, Col E, Col F, Col G], 
 [1, A, 8, [(P0, 1), (P2, 7), (P1, 1)],1,7,1],
 [2, B, 4, [(P2, 4)],0,4,0],
 [3, C, 13,[(P2, 1)],0,1,0]]]
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code you tried already.

Comment: It's not clear how "these three columns should have parsed values from Col C" works: Can you explain why row 1 has output `1, 7, 1` for E, F, G, row 2 is `0, 4, 0` etc??

Comment: @Bardy - Sorry for the typo - These three columns should have parsed values form Col D

Comment: @RobinGertenbach - https://jsfiddle.net/szxq41qc/2/

Comment: Still isn't clear. E.g. why `0, 4, 0` not `4, 0, 0`?

Comment: Col E, Col F, Col G => maps to P0,P1 and P2

Comment: @Bardy so for [(P2, 4)]] ->0,4,0

Comment: P seems to stand for position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

It goes through each row, adds [0,0,0] and replaces the 0's by a number at the position as long as it can find substitution rules.

Be aware that I do an assignment in the while, which is not unusual when workin with generators like this.

```
data6.map(function(row) {
  var toExpand = row[row.length-1];
  var indices = /(?:\(P)(\d)/g;
  var splitter = /(\d)(?:\))/g;
  var extracted;
  var eIndex;

  toAdd = [0,0,0];
  while(extracted = splitter.exec(toExpand)) {
    eIndex = indices.exec(toExpand);
    toAdd[eIndex[1]] = extracted[1];
  }
  return row.concat(toAdd);
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/szxq41qc/5/ - Can you take a look at the code and see what the error. I can't get the final output.

Comment: Sorry, i should have put it more into context of your code, this replaces everything after the definition of data6. You can store the return value of this map operation in a variable or pass it somewhere else. It's one statement with the desired output as a return.

Comment: Thanks Robin for the code snippet will use to make it working.